# XSS: Why does an alert get fired when this javascript string is assigned?

Tags: javascript, xss

I'm investigating an XSS issue, which can be duplicated in the following simple html file, which when loaded, shows an alert with the value of "1".

Why does this work? The `title` string has an alert script tag in it, but I'm surprised the browser renders it, as that `</script>` tag is in a string?

## test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script>
        var title = "</script><svg/onload=alert(1)>";
      </script>
    </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Note, I've simplified the example to a simple string assignment.

Comment: Because the script ends at `</script>`.

Comment: "*Is the only way to protect against this is to html encode all attribute values in a json object?*" - the proper way of protection is to html-encode the *whole script*. Not just the JSON, or just the property values in the JSON.

Comment: @Bergi - You can't do that: http://jsfiddle.net/f67xq3vk/ The content of a `script` tag is not HTML text (whereas the content of an attribute, even `onclick` and such, is).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Did I write html-encode? Oops. Yes, you cannot use html entity escapes, one has to escape the content appropriately for script tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `</script>` inside the `title` string ends your script, so the following `svg` is part of the HTML.

To protect against that:

1. Don't use inline script, or
2. If you do, **any** user-sourced input you render in it needs to not have `</script>` in it. (I'd probably be paranoid and allow for whitespace between the `<` and `/` and `script` and `>`; in a JavaScript regex, `<\s*/\s*script\s*>` with the `m` flag.)

For #2, encoding entities would work, or just insert a backslash in front of the slash in the content. If you do that (server side), then you'd have:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script>
        var test = {
          "id" : 12181,
          "title" : "<\\/script><svg/onload=alert(1)>",
          "email" : null
        };
      </script>

    </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

...which won't alert. (I only added one backslash, but of course, that's inside a string literal, so it will get escaped.)

**However**, if you're putting untrusted content in your pages, you'd be well-served by reading through the [owasp.org XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). The above may be sufficient for *this one specific use*, but you may want to go further and you certainly will want to do HTML escaping on any content you include in HTML (rather than script) elements, in attributes (which are HTML text, even if they're `onclick` and such), etc.

Comment: Probably safer to go the long way and do something like `JSON.parse(decodeURI("..."))` and pass an encoded string to it.

Comment: @riv - How, specifically, would that be "safer"?

Comment: For instance, you wouldn't forget to escape a `</script>` in an key name. I'm not sure if there are other ways to break out of script, but full HTML escape is usually suggested.

Comment: See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet rule 3.1.

Comment: @riv - Presumably the key is not user-generated. But fair enough. Note that the concern Rule 3.1 is trying to address is the one I already addressed above; the rule doesn't say anything about using URI-encoding or similar, nor other vectors other than the `</script>` issue. In any case, added a note.

Comment: Yeah we are html encoding our content, but this slipped through the cracks because we weren't html encoding the entire javascript object that was being output there... I just don't see why the browser would think that that ending script tag was actually closing the script tag is all.

Comment: @BradParks - Because that's how script tags work. Remember that the HTML parser is not a JavaScript parser (much less a parser of every other possible format you might put in a script tag with a `type` attribute). So when it sees `<script>`, it scans for `</script>` and stops at the first one it finds. That's the end of that script tag. Doesn't matter if it's in the middle of a string literal, because the HTML parser doesn't know that.

Comment: Yeah i get that now... Makes sense in a way, but ultimately, very unexpected, and unintuitive!